# Do atoms like WM_DELETE_WINDOW not have constant values?

Tags: c++, c, x11, xlib, xcb

I'm learning how to work with X11 using XCB. And I've seen examples that basically query the server for the atom of `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` by doing something like this:

```
auto cookie = xcb_intern_atom(conn, 0, strlen("WM_DELETE_WINDOW"), "WM_DELETE_WINDOW");
auto reply = xcb_intern_atom_reply(conn, cookie, NULL);
auto wmDeleteAtom = reply->atom;
free(reply);
```

My question is why is this necessary? Why is the WM_DELETE_WINDOW atom not defined in a header like `XCB_ATOM_WM_NAME` is? Can I define it myself, or is this process necessary because the atom is not the same # on every system?

Comment: I suggest you tag your question with a language if you want anyone to see it.

Comment: @miken32 OK, I can do that

Comment: I meant the one that you’re using

Comment: @Miken32 I don't understand why it would matter. It's a C API. If you are familiar with any of the client libraries for X11 I think it would be obvious you are using C/C++. And the language is really not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The `xcb_intern_atom` queries the server if a property exist, in your case, if the `"WM_DELETE_WINDOW"` property is supported by some client, here, the Windows Manager.

You query properties using their names, ie using a string.

In your query, `"WM_DELETE_WINDOW"` is just a string, not a scalar previously defined.

The `X Server` does not know about this property until it is defined by some clients.
So, you will not find anything about `"WM_DELETE_WINDOW"` which is certainly defined by your Windows Manager.

Before doing something in `X`, you must acquire some information on supported features.
`xcb_intern_atom` is the equivalent of the `XLIB XInternAtom`, which both return an `'Atom'`, ie a structure as an identifier to a property.

You ask the `X` Server what is the identifier/atom for a single property, like "WM_DELETE_WINDOW".
It's like saying :

- "hey guy, do you support/have this property ? "

and the server could reply

- "yes, I know it, and the identifier I use is ..."

Your `X server` keep trace on properties previously defined by some clients, but it does not define them itself.

Your `X server` is just the guy that create relationships between clients, sharing their properties through `atoms`.

The identifier/Atom (`xcb_intern_atom_cookie_t`) returned by `xcb_intern_atom` is next send through protocols (see `ICCCM`), eg through an event, to inform you that the window manager generate a `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` (ie the user has clicked on the Close button of a Window).

Once you get it, you can take action, like exiting or closing a Window.
These are all conventions.

The way `X` manages its clients is a bit tricky, but once you get it, it's really easy to understand.

IMHO, because the API is in `C`, better use `C` in order to understand how it works and what are the name of the structures you are using (sorry, but `C++ auto` is not why you need at the beginning).

Comment: I'm going to disagree about auto. I've looked into the X11 spec and it seems to me that the actual 32bit value that corresponds to "WM_DELETE_WINDOW " would indeed vary and therefore I see why it can't be defined to prevent server requests.